# How can I add vertical line and label for each point in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

How can I add a vertical line for each point and make the selected data to appear with a 5.5k label like on the below screenshot?

[image: Chart with vertical lines]

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: @hali aswad: I answered your question "How can I add a vertical line for each point?". You should however not include multiple questions in the same post. Accordingly, please post a new question for the other issue "how can I make selected data is highlighted...?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw your own lines directly on to the `canvas` using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). It offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In below code snippet, I use the `afterDraw` hook to draw vertical lines up to the individual points from the dataset.

```js
const data = [65, 0, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40];

new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, index) => {
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);
        var yTop = yAxis.getPixelForValue(data[index]);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#aaaaaa';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, yAxis.bottom);
        ctx.lineTo(x, yTop);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
      });
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: data,
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],    
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]    
    }
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js'></script>
<div style="width: 75%">
  <canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great solution. Can you make the label(5.5k) at top of the point-like screenshot and also for this point bottom labell is highlighted